# React.js - app works when running from npm start, but won't build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compilation

I'm new to React.js and was unsure why my app won't build properly.
The app functions as I expect (returning/displaying the JSON from the API call) when I run it via npm start, but npm run build results in the following error:

The compilation message (it just stays there):
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4al3.png)

I've tried adding/removing .catch() after my async statements but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

OS: Windows 10
React: 17.0.2

Form.js:

```js
import {useState} from 'react' 

const Form = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState('')

    const fetchData = async() => {
        const res = await fetch("https://avwx.rest/api/metar/" + text, 
            {headers : {"Authorization": "key"}})
            .catch((error) => {return Promise.reject()})
        const rawJSON = await res.json().catch((error) => {return Promise.reject()})
        console.log(rawJSON)
        setData(rawJSON)
    }
    
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (text.length !== 4) {
            alert("Input valid ICAO airport code")
            return
        }
        
        fetchData()
        setText('')
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit = {onSubmit}>
          <div className = "lbl">
            <label>
              Airport Code (ICAO): {' '}
            </label>
          </div>
          <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>     
          <input className = 'btn' type="submit" value="Go" />
          <p className = "data">{JSON.stringify(data.raw, null, 2)}</p>
        </form> 
    )
}

export default Form
```

The build script:

```js
{
  "name": "metar_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to fetch data you can use below snippet, if it can help you

```
const fetchData = async () => {  
await fetch(url, { method })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    setData(json)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("from error", err);        
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log("from finally");                
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that it was unhappy with my padding in the CSS for the button. Once I removed that line it compiled without errors.